# How to catch an exception for sodium_crypto_box

Tags: php, libsodium

I am trying to see if the message gets corrupted in the middle I should be able to get an error but all I am seeing is a white page.

```
<?php 
$keypair = hex2bin('66b70b4e93416f8a7a82a40a856fe9884fd7a6e5018837c5421f507307026b40b2c8fbaf820ee38198af1dcf23143ec7ae21da1c785f58d1053940b9f317180e');
$encrypted_text = hex2bin('de261df126463f57b6c38bf42b69252b2f9382267b51e137e20e27ace37c5853279b00c95536cc9a44945146376c5d94355ae0bab5c1eb0ceb9669002ee5dd13e7aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa');
$decrypted_text = sodium_crypto_box_seal_open($encrypted_text, $keypair);
echo $decrypted_text;
?>
```

As you can see there are aaaaaaaaaaaaaa in the end in $encrypted_text I should get an error but there is no error.

Comment: Why just not check if the `$decrypted_text` is empty? And if it is throw an exception.

Comment: That worked, thanks.

Comment: _“but all I am seeing is a white page”_ - well you are not catching an exception in the code shown, and if you don’t do it later on somewhere, that will result in a Fatal Error when the script is through. Combine that with PHP being gagged by unsuitable error reporting setting, and the result you get is a blank page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`sodium_crypto_box_seal_open()` returns `FALSE` if the message cannot be decrypted.

You should compare its output against `FALSE`, not check if it is empty, as it is perfectly fine to encrypt an empty message. Empty messages are authenticated and will be rejected if the key is not correct.

Also, if secrets are involved, you should use `sodium_bin2hex()` and `sodium_hex2bin()`, that are designed to avoid side channels

Answer (score 0):

Libsodium functions are low-level. Either use any [wrapper package](https://packagist.org/?query=libsodium) to ease use, or create one by yourself:

```
interface Decryptor
{
    public function decrypt(string $input): string;
}

final class LibsodiumDecryptor implements Decryptor
{
    private $keyPair;

    public function __construct(string $keyPair)
    {
        $this->keyPair = hex2bin($keyPair);
    }

    public function decrypt(string $input): string
    {
        $decrypted = sodium_crypto_box_seal_open(hex2bin($input), $this->keyPair);

        if (empty($decrypted)) {
            throw new \RuntimeException('Encryption failed');
        }

        return $decrypted;
    }
}

$crypto = new LibsodiumDecryptor('66b70b4e93416f8a7a82a40a856…');

echo $crypto->decrypt('de261df126463f57b6aaaaaaaaaaa…');
```